# How do I modify Adxstudio online's aspx file?

Tags: dynamics-crm, adxstudio-portals

How do I modify Adxstudio online's aspx file?

For example, `Case` Page Template is linked to an aspx file at `~/Areas/HelpDesk/Pages/Case.aspx`. How do I modify that `Case.aspx` file? I've looked around in both CRM and Adxstudio portal site but still cannot find any aspx file.

I'm using Adxstudio online trial, version 7 and CRM Online 2016.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working in an online trial of Adxstudio I suspect you won't have access to the server side code files.

If you want to edit the server side code you should [download](https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/releases/adxstudio-portals-7/download/) the SDK, that has all the aspx files in. You can then self host the portal, whilst having full access to the aspx files in something like Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Is this Adxstudio Cloud Service? 
https://www.adxstudio.com/adxstudio-portals/features/cloud-hosted-saas/

If so, the answer is you cannot. For the cloud offering, you get what they give you out of the box.

If you are using the on-premise or 'standard' version - you download the SDK which contains a sample/starter project. Open that, configure the connection string and then you can edit the ASPXs (Page Templates) in the Pages folder.